# How do I write a test for the failing request to an API made in the viewModelScope in Android?

Tags: android, repository-pattern, android-testing, android-viewmodel

I have a view model which creates a mutable state using a sealed interface.

My question is How do I write a test when the repository returns a `Result.failure(e)` in order to assert that the `marsUiState` can be equal to `MarsUIState.Error`?

Here is the **MarsUiState** which I use to set the general state of the app.

```
sealed interface MarsUiState<out T> {
    data class Success<out T>(val photos: T) : MarsUiState<T>
    data class Error<out T: Throwable>(val error: T) : MarsUiState<Nothing>
    data object Loading : MarsUiState<Nothing>
}
```

Here is the **ViewModel**

```
class MarsViewModel(
    private val marsPhotosRepository: MarsPhotosRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    /** The mutable State that stores the status of the most recent request */
    var marsUiState: MarsUiState<List<MarsPhoto>> by mutableStateOf(MarsUiState.Loading)
        private set

    /**
     * Call getMarsPhotos() on init so we can display status immediately.
     */
    init {
        getMarsPhotos()
    }

    /**
     * Gets Mars photos information from the Mars API
     */
    internal fun getMarsPhotos() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            marsUiState = marsPhotosRepository.getMarsPhotos().fold(
                onSuccess = {
                    MarsUiState.Success(it)
                },
                onFailure = {
                    Log.d("viewModel Exception", "$it")
                    MarsUiState.Error(it)
                }
            )
        }
    }    
    
}
```

Here is the **Repository** which returns a `Result` object

```
fun interface MarsPhotosRepository {
    suspend fun getMarsPhotos(): Result<List<MarsPhoto>>
}

class NetworkMarsPhotosRepository(private val service: MarsApiService) : MarsPhotosRepository {
    override suspend fun getMarsPhotos(): Result<List<MarsPhoto>> =
        try {
            val response = service.getPhotos()
            Result.success(response)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Result.failure(e)
        }

}
```

This is the **Retrofit service** used to get the photos:

```
fun interface MarsApiService {

    @GET("photos")
    suspend fun getPhotos(): List<MarsPhoto>
}
```

This is the **MarsPhoto** model:

```
@Serializable
data class MarsPhoto(
    @SerialName("id") val id: String,
    @SerialName("img_src") val imgSrc: String,
)
```

This is what I have tried to use to test the `.onFailure()` block of code but still does not work. The class `FakeFailingMarsApiService(IOException())` is just a dumb fake that throws `IOException` when calling its method.

```
    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@Test
fun `When connection fails, IOException is cached and uiState is set to Error`() = runTest {
    val expectedState: MarsUiState<Nothing> = MarsUiState.Error(IOException())
    val throwableRepository = NetworkMarsPhotosRepository(FakeFailingMarsApiService(IOException()))
    val viewModelTest = MarsViewModel(throwableRepository)
    viewModelTest.getMarsPhotos()
    val realState = viewModelTest.marsUiState
    advanceTimeBy(10000)
    runCurrent()
    assertEquals(expectedState, realState)
}
```

Failing test result:

```
Expected :Error(error=java.io.IOException)
Actual   :Loading
```

Comment: Can you post the source for MarsPhoto and MarsApiService as well. I can have a look.

Comment: of course! there you have them :D